# Where to put 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' for build in TFS2012

Tags: unit-testing, tfsbuild

While i'm locally get the error in a unit test:

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of 
the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without 
additional configuration information
```

And the solution is to add

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

to the config file located in

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.config
```

This still is going wrong on our TFS2012 build server. I also added the startup tags to the file on the TFS2012, but the build server reports the error.

How do I get this to work on a unit test project (using the new unit test framework of VS2012 & TFS2012) in a build definition?

Comment: That is the correct .config to be updated. Are there any other errors you are running into?

Answer (score 1):

While having problems to get it running on TFS too, you might give it a try to set it programmatically (e.g. using [this approach](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/)). While I would not recommend using that in productive code it should be perfectly sufficient when it comes to UnitTests.